# Как вызвать метод из dll C# в C++ (Qt)?

Tags: c#, c++, qt

Как пример кусок кода:

```
namespace HelloWorldDll {
  public class printElements {
    public static string Foo() => "hello c++";
  }
}
```

Небольшая схемка. Основная проблема сделать экспорт классов, с функциями разобрался, спасибо за помощь в прежних ответах. Дали пищу для размышлений
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: C# - управляемый язык для разработки под платформу .NET. Следовательно, чтобы эта dll работала, нужен этот самый .NET. Вы точно этого хотите?

Comment: да, есть библиотеки dll  к api софта на C#. Сделал небольшое приложение на шарпе. Из некоторых соображений защиты подумал его переписать на C++, вообще - это возможно? Понятно, мелкое приложение таким способом защищать нет смысла

Comment: [ActiveQt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/activeqt-dotnet.html).

Comment: Unmanaged Exports вам в помощь

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо загрузить CLR в процесс. Есть статья на MSDN и неплохой пример на codeproject:

- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppHostCLR-e6581ee0
- https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607352/Injecting-Net-Assemblies-Into-Unmanaged-Processes

Однако стоит учитывать, что кроссплатформенностью в данном случае придется пожертвовать.

Comment: к сожалению это не то. Мне не нужен CLR. Необходимо экспортировать класс, даже не функцию используя С++, чтобы потом сделать импорт в шарп

Comment: @std2017 не понял Вас, Вам надо функцию, написанную на C++ вызвать из .NET или все же наоборот?

Comment: верно вызвать из C#. Но больше, 
1. класс написанный в С++ обернуть в dll
2. эту dll C++, например, в ней класс Point с координатами точки, использовать в другом своем dll приложении C#, 
3. мой c# dll юзает методы такого же класса (с тем же именем), но из dll c предоставленным api на C#. 
Схему прикладываю. https://cloud.mail.ru/public/Bri3/kCxVuXhmK

Answer (score 0):

В C# есть System.Runtime.InteropServices;

```
public class MyApi
{
    [DllImport("MyAppDll.dll")] // relative path; just give the DLL's name
    static extern bool MyGreatFunction(int myFirstParam, int mySecondParam);
}
```

Подробнее про extern https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/extern